# Deck V Brace Alternatives

Tags: deck, joists, brackets

I have a V brace underneath my deck for stability, but I'd like to replace it with something that fits between joists. Im putting in an under deck ceiling and the V brace takes up some head room, so was hoping there were other ideas. I found some sway braces but my joists are about 11 inches apart, and the sway braces are 12 and 16 inch options.

Can I use wood 2x8's between joists, recreating the V formation? Seems like a lot of work putting in brackets on each board but if that would work I'd try it.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Pictures, pictures, we love pictures.

Comment: Pictures will be better, but if it is what I think, you might be able to notch the joists so the braces are not in the way.  Pictures will probably prove I do not know what I am talking about.

Comment: Whoops thx for the reminder, picture added

Comment: Why not throw some blocking between the joists?

Comment: Yeah I guess that's an option too, I just wanted to avoid having to add a bunch of brackets to keep the blocks in place. I've seen pictures where people just hold them in with 3 inch nails but that doesn't seem like it'll last that long. The flat tension bracing seems like a good alternative but here in the US they don't really sell the same stuff. Or at least not what Rohit posted.

Comment: More I research about it I think blocks will be the way to go. The length is ~9 feet, so blocks at around 4.5 feet all the way down should make it strong enough.

Answer (score 1):

These **flat tension bracing** are quite common in Australia and New Zealand.

[image: Bracing]

It would be faster to install it too.  Just nail it to the bottom of the joists (beams).  You can get them in galvanized iron or stainless.

Comment: Interesting, so basically replace the 2x4's with the flat tension bracing in the same V pattern?

Comment: That is correct.  It used to be used all the time for bracing walls, trusses, joists.